Does the solution for the system also satisfies the second diff. eq,?
consider the following system $x_1'=3x_1+x_2$, $x_2'=-x_1+x_2$, with $x_1(0)=1, x_2((0)=0 $. The solution is $$X_1=\begin{pmatrix}
  {-e^{2t}} \\
  {e^{2t}} \\
\end{pmatrix}\,\, ;X_2=\begin{pmatrix}
  {-e^{2t}} \\
  {0} \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
So, $y=c_1 X_1+c_2(X_2+tX_1)$
Also, I can write the above system as second differential equation for $x_1$, $x_1''-4x_1'+4x_1=0$ which has a solution $x_1=c_1 e^{2t}+c_2 t e^{2t}.$ My question is How can I show $X_1$ is solution for $x_1''-4x_1'+4x_1=0.$

Actually your equation is for $x_1$ which is one dimensional, and $X_1$ is two-dimensionnal. May you prefer writing : $X'=AX$ with $X=(x_1,x_2)$.

@00GB: Did the solution resolve your issues?

First, let's solve the second order ODE
$$x_1'' -4x_1'+4x_1 = 0, x_1(0) = 1, x_1'(0) = 3$$
We have
$$x_1(t) = e^{2 t} (t+1)$$
Now, let's look at the system of first-order equations
$$X'(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1' \\x_2' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix}, X(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
This matrix has a repeated eigenvalue, $\lambda = -2$, and is defective, so we need a generalized eigenvector. We find those as
$$ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Use your approach with those eigenvalues/eigenvectors and see if it matches the approach I use.
We find the matrix exponential (there are many ways to solve these and it looks like you have an issue) as
$$\phi(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
 e^{2 t} (t+1) & t e^{2 t} \\
 - t e^{2 t} & e^{2 t} (1-t) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Using this, we can write the solution as
$$X(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{pmatrix} = c_1 \begin{pmatrix} e^{2t} (t+1) \\ - t e^{2 t} \end{pmatrix} + c_2 \begin{pmatrix} t e^{2 t} \\ e^{2 t} (1-t) \end{pmatrix}$$
Using the ICs, we find $c_1 = 1, c_2 = 0$ and have
$$X(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} e^{2 t} (t+1) \\ -e^{2 t} \end{pmatrix} $$
Now, just compare the solution for this $x_1(t)$ with the one above - they are identical.
You are comparing a one-dimensional ($x_1(t)$) to a two dimensional ($X(t)$ result, but only need $x_1(t)$ in this case.
Of course $X(t)$ will satisfy the two-dimensional system and you can also check that by using the solution and verifying that the left-hand side = the right-hand side. That is, substitute this solution into the LHS and RHS of the system and verify LHS = RHS.

thank you for your solution
